# Angular2 : NG2-Simple-Timer is Not Loaded

Tags: angular

I am trying to ember `ng2-simple-timer` module in my application ,but it seems that I am doing something wrong wollowing the instructions from the web site (I hope I put all the relevant information):

1. I have ran `npm install ng2-simple-timer --save` and then added `SimpleTimer` to `providers` array in `app.module`. Trying to load the app caused an error: `GET http://localhost:3000/ng2-simple-timer 404 (Not Found)`. This is because the module was installed under `node_modules`.
2. Following instructions from other examples, I have added the following line to `systemjs.config.js`:  `'ng2-simple-timer': 'npm:ng2-simple-timer/index.js'`. This caused the error: `GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-simple-timer/lib/simple-timer 404 (Not Found)`. If I understand correctly, this is because `simple-timer` is pure JS module and not Typescript.
3. I removed the above line and added the following: `///<reference path="../node_modules/ng2-simple-timer/index.d.ts" />` to `typings/index.d.ts` and `<script src="node_modules/ng2-simple-timer/index.js"></script>` to `index.html`, but this still caused the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined index.js:1`

So what is the correct way to include this module in my application?

Comment: Which angular2 version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Following is `systemjs.config.js` I used in my [ng2-simple-timer-example](https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-timer-example). The example is updated to support angular2 2.4.x.

```
(function (global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'ng2-simple-timer': 'node_modules/ng2-simple-timer',
    'angular2-uuid': 'node_modules/angular2-uuid'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { main: 'bundles/Rx.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-simple-timer': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-uuid': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic'
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```